ValueError solving generalized eigenvalue problem with scipy
Hi I am trying to solve a generalized eigenvalue problem (GEVP) on a correlator matrix.
The part of the code that is giving me problem is:
    import scipy.linalg as la


    [...]




    corr_j = simple_corr(data_jack, mask)

    
    #compute the eigenvalues
    eig_j = np.zeros((nOps, L0, L0))


    for t0 in range(2,L0//2-1):
        for t1 in range(t0+1, L0//2):

            #solve the generalized eigenvalue problem C(t) v = lambda(t) C(t0) v

            C = corr_j[:,:,t1]
            C0 = corr_j[:,:,t0]

            print(f"C = {C.shape}")
            print(f"C = {C}")
            print(f"C0 = {C0.shape}")
            print(f"C0 = {C0}")
            eig_t = la.eig(C, b = C0)

All the print calls are there for debugging purposes. And to show you that the matrices are of the correct shape and are not empty or singular.
This piece of code is inside a function called gevp_jack(data,mask)that should perform this GEVP for many different jacknife samples.
When i run the code i get the following output:
C = (7, 7)
C = [[ 1.59584972 -2.15633651  1.24114058  1.75321492 -1.81777217  1.81941323
  -0.91749864]
 [-2.15633651  2.9590494  -1.68747421 -2.40047725  2.50849557 -2.51730532
   1.25051207]
 [ 1.24114058 -1.68747421  0.98367127  1.37224169 -1.40936567  1.40846551
  -0.72515541]
 [ 1.75321492 -2.40047725  1.37224169  1.9320236  -1.99770539  2.00577185
  -1.01332363]
 [-1.81777217  2.50849557 -1.40936567 -1.99770539  2.17348089 -2.16582443
   1.08016084]
 [ 1.81941323 -2.51730532  1.40846551  2.00577185 -2.16582443  2.15743968
  -1.09213161]
 [-0.91749864  1.25051207 -0.72515541 -1.01332363  1.08016084 -1.09213161
   0.51369853]]
C0 = (7, 7)
C0 = [[ 5.09266872 -6.49228588  4.14126736  5.37497589 -4.90238238  5.82926292
  -3.01593039]
 [-6.49228588  8.46178084 -5.22826411 -6.92532952  6.49513817 -7.44136205
   3.78233514]
 [ 4.14126736 -5.22826411  3.40637298  4.36963407 -3.89903505  4.7350309
  -2.4841818 ]
 [ 5.37497589 -6.92532952  4.36963407  5.68667154 -5.23611244  6.14753923
  -3.16321806]
 [-4.90238238  6.49513817 -3.89903505 -5.23611244  5.28974258 -5.64769213
   2.79528734]
 [ 5.82926292 -7.44136205  4.7350309   6.14753923 -5.64769213  6.65394343
  -3.42858045]
 [-3.01593039  3.78233514 -2.4841818  -3.16321806  2.79528734 -3.42858045
   1.80604997]]
Unexpected exception formatting exception. Falling back to standard exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/andrea/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3526, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "/tmp/ipykernel_4321/229272726.py", line 2, in <module>
    eig, err_eig = gu.gevp_jack(data, mask)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/andrea/Documents/[...]/gevp_utils.py", line 378, in gevp_jack
    eig_t = np.sort(eig_t)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 200, in sort
  File "/home/andrea/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 1029, in sort
    a = asanyarray(a).copy(order="K")
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 2 dimensions. The detected shape was (2, 7) + inhomogeneous part.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/andrea/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2120, in showtraceback
    stb = self.InteractiveTB.structured_traceback(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/andrea/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 1435, in structured_traceback
    return FormattedTB.structured_traceback(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/andrea/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 1326, in structured_traceback
    return VerboseTB.structured_traceback(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/andrea/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 1173, in structured_traceback
    formatted_exception = self.format_exception_as_a_whole(etype, evalue, etb, number_of_lines_of_context,
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/andrea/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 1088, in format_exception_as_a_whole
    frames.append(self.format_record(record))
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/andrea/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 970, in format_record
    frame_info.lines, Colors, self.has_colors, lvals
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/andrea/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 792, in lines
    return self._sd.lines
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/andrea/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/stack_data/utils.py", line 145, in cached_property_wrapper
    value = obj.__dict__[self.func.__name__] = self.func(obj)
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/andrea/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/stack_data/core.py", line 698, in lines
    pieces = self.included_pieces
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/andrea/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/stack_data/utils.py", line 145, in cached_property_wrapper
    value = obj.__dict__[self.func.__name__] = self.func(obj)
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/andrea/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/stack_data/core.py", line 649, in included_pieces
    pos = scope_pieces.index(self.executing_piece)
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/andrea/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/stack_data/utils.py", line 145, in cached_property_wrapper
    value = obj.__dict__[self.func.__name__] = self.func(obj)
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/andrea/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/stack_data/core.py", line 628, in executing_piece
    return only(
           ^^^^^
  File "/home/andrea/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/executing/executing.py", line 164, in only
    raise NotOneValueFound('Expected one value, found 0')
executing.executing.NotOneValueFound: Expected one value, found 0

I don't know what i am doing wrong, it seems to refer to an array of inhomogenous size but my array are all normal innocent square matrices

Please provide a [mre]. We should be able to just copy and paste your code, run it, and see for ourselves what you see. So far, we can't. Firstly, [...] is not legal python, import are missing, and indentation is wrong. But more importantly (since those are painful, but we could solve them on our side, even if we shouldn't have to), we don't know what data_jack or mask are.  I understand that you can't copy all irrelevant part of the code. That is even a requirements of [mre] (the M of MRE). But the R is also important. Replace real data with some inline hard-coded data

even rewriting some code part to remove irrelevant transformation if needed.

The traceback of this function mentions a line eig_t = np.sort(eig_t). Since this is what causes the rest of the error, can you include this code?

I'm not sure if this is what's happening, but scipy.linalg.eig() returns a tuple of both the eigenvalues and eigenvectors. Are you perhaps passing this directly into np.sort()? That could cause your error, since the eigenvalues will have shape (7,), but the eigenvectors will have shape (7, 7). If that's the problem, you would need to call it like eigenvalues, eigenvectors = la.eig(C, b = C0)

The 'inhomogeneous' error means a is ragged, it can't make a nd numeric array,

yeah sorry i understand it's not reproducible like this. I hoped that the problem was much more stupid and could be solved just by looking at the error message, i will check if  np.sort is causing the issue, if that's not the case ill'rephrase the question into something you guyys can work with more easily

Can you look at eig_t the argument to the sort?  sort is trying to turn it into a regular numpy numeric array so it can sort it.
